# Problems when testing directives with an isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

It seems that I am unable to obtain a reference to the proper scope when running tests on directives with an *isolated* scope. Just to be clear I don't have this problem for tests that inherit scope.

The problem shows itself when, for the `$httpBackend.expectPOST()` call, I specify the expected data.

```
$httpBackend.expectPOST('/notes/'+scope.note.id+'/replies', {
  content: 'This is the reply'        /*** TEST PASSES IF EXPECTED POST DATA IS NOT SET ***/
}).respond(200, {
  id: 11,
  noteId: 199,
  content: 'This is the reply'
});
```

When I call `elem.find('[ng-click="saveReply()"]').click()`, the scope saveReply() **is** called, but none of the data that was set gets submitted so the if I specify the expected data it fails, but if I don't specify the expected data it passes.  Obviously, to have more complete tests I would like to perform the former.

As mentioned above the saveReply() method is called after calling the click() method.  Which would lead one to think that the proper scope binding is in place, but if I directly set a scope variable it still is not seen in scope method.  Maybe this is where the issue/solution is...

I would think that the required scope reference could be obtained via `elem.scope()`, but when I do that elem.scope() is the same as $rootScope.

```
// FAILS
expect(elem.scope().$id).not.toEqual($rootScope.$id);
```

Any ideas?

```
'use strict';

describe('Note directive', function () {

  var scope, elem;

  var compile = function($compile, $rootScope, PhotoService) {
    spyOn(PhotoService, 'profilePhotoUrl').andReturn('mypic.jpg');
    scope = $rootScope;
    scope.note = {
      id: 199,
      content: 'This is the note',
      author: {
        firstName: 'Jim',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        name: 'Jim Smith',
        profilePhotoName: 'mypic.jpg'
      },
      replies: [
        {id: 99, content: 'you should not see this on initial load', author: {
          firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Smith', name: 'Jim Smith', profilePhotoName: 'mypic.jpg'}
        },
        {id: 99, content: 'but you should see this one', author: {
          firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Smith', name: 'Jim Smith', profilePhotoName: 'mypic.jpg'}
        }
      ]
    };
    elem = $compile('<note data="note"></note>')(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  };

  var stubCurrentUser = function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/users/me').respond({id: 99, name: 'Jim Smith', role: 'owner'});
  };

  beforeEach(module('woddy'));
  beforeEach(module('directive_templates'));
  beforeEach(inject(stubCurrentUser, compile));

  iit('allows the user to reply to a note', inject(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('/notes/'+scope.note.id+'/replies', {
      content: 'This is the reply'        /*** TEST PASSES IF EXPECTED POST DATA IS NOT SET ***/
    }).respond(200, {
      id: 11,
      noteId: 199,
      content: 'This is the reply'
    });

    expect(elem.find('[ng-repeat="reply in note.replies"]').length).toBe(2);
    elem.find('[ng-click="reply()"]').click();
    scope.$digest();
    elem.find('[ng-model="content"]').text("This is the reply");
    scope.$digest();
    elem.find('[ng-click="saveReply()"]').click();

    $httpBackend.flush();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();

    scope.$digest();
    expect(elem.find('[ng-repeat="reply in note.replies"]').length).toBe(3);
  }));

});
```

Directive

```
'use strict';

angular.module('woddy').directive('note', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      note: '=data'
    },
    templateUrl: '/dashboard/note.html',

    controller: function($scope, PhotoService, Reply, CurrentUser) {

      $scope.state = 'show';
      $scope.showAllReplies = false;

      CurrentUser.get().then(function(user) {
        $scope.currentUser = user;
      });

      /**
       * Reply on the note
       */
      $scope.reply = function() {
        $scope.content = '';
        $scope.state = 'add';
      };

      /**
       * Revert back to the default view
       */
      $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.content = 'Add a comment...';
        $scope.state = 'show';
      };

      $scope.saveReply = function() {
        console.log("It is calling the method")
        var reply = new Reply({
          noteId: $scope.note.id,
          content: $scope.content
        });

        reply.$save(function() {
          var author = $scope.currentUser;
          $scope.note.replies.push({
            content: $scope.content,
            author: {
              id: author.id,
              name: author.name,
              photoName: author.photoName,
              gender: author.gender
            }
          });

          $scope.reset();
        });
      };

    }
  };
});
```

View

```
<div class="note box">
  <img class="author" ng-src="{{authorPhotoUrl()}}" alt="{{note.author.name}}"/>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="name" ng-bind="note.author.name"></div>
    <div class="timestamp" timestamp="{{note.timestamp}}"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="content" ng-bind-html="note.content"></div>

  <div class="note-replies" ng-if="note.replies.length > 0">
    <div class="links">
      <span>{{note.replies.length}} {{note.replies.length == 1 ? 'Comment' : 'Comments'}}</span>
      <a href="#" ng-show="!showAllReplies && note.replies.length > 1" ng-click="showAllReplies = true">Show Comments</a>
      <a href="#" ng-show="showAllReplies && note.replies.length > 1" ng-click="showAllReplies = false">Hide Comments</a>
    </div>

    <div class="replies">
      <div class="reply" ng-repeat="reply in note.replies" ng-show="showAllReplies || $last">
        <img ng-src="{{replyAuthorPhotoUrl(reply.author)}}" alt="{{reply.author.name}}">
        <div class="reply-details">
          <span class="name" ng-bind="reply.author.name"></span>
          <span class="timestamp" timestamp="{{reply.timestamp}}"></span>
          <div class="content" ng-bind-html="reply.content"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="reply-form">
    <div class="reply-content" ng-click="reply()" contenteditable="true" ng-model="content">Add a comment...</div>
    <form ng-show="state == 'add'">
      <div class="text-right">
        <button class="secondary" ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>
        <button ng-click="saveReply()">Comment</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJs 1.2 you can use `elem.isolateScope()` to access the directive isolate scope.

Here is a plunker example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/x0c0HYfyVMfsV8LX2bZX?p=preview

Comment: This is one of the answers I got off of the IRC board, but in this case isolateScope() returns null.  The issue is really why are form element value settings ignored. ex `elem.find('[ng-model="content"]').text("This is the reply")` // this value does not make it to the httpBackend

Comment: Do you have a custom ```contenteditable``` directive?  Angular does not support ```contenteditable``` out of the box though there are plenty of examples. The issue is documented [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/528)

Comment: I do and it works well when using the app through a browser, however it is  all the data, not just the contenteditable bound data, that is not being submitted.

Comment: Not having the complete code makes it difficult to debug. Can you reproduce the issue in a plunker?